# {[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet} DEBUG - Exiting from "ASYNC" dispatch - http response remains empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm revamping the Spring Web application to Spring Reactive Web.

Upon adding new controllers that return Mono and Flux whenever I call from postman I get a 200 HTTP response code but with an empty body/response.

In the console, I can see the following lines getting printed.

> 022-08-23 15:00:11.315 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=kashif]
> [request_id=8df3ef65-e9b7-4aaf-b3ef-65e9b7eaaf31]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]
> DEBUG - Mapped to
> org.dummy.services.controller.TestController#hello()
> 2022-08-23 15:00:11.315 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=kashif]
> [request_id=8df3ef65-e9b7-4aaf-b3ef-65e9b7eaaf31]
> [org.dummy.services.controller.TestController] INFO - POI hello  2022-08-23 15:00:11.315 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=qaz] [request_id=8aaaaaaaaaaaaaf31]
> [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager] DEBUG - Started async request  2022-08-23 15:00:11.315 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=qaz]
> [request_id=8aaaaaaaaaaaaaf31]
> [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager] DEBUG - Async result set, dispatch to /poi/test/hello  2022-08-23 15:00:11.315 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=qaz]
> [request_id=8df3ef65-e9b7-4aaf-b3ef-65e9b7eaaf31]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DEBUG - Exiting
> but response remains open for further handling  2022-08-23
> 15:00:11.346 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=] [request_id=]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DEBUG - "ASYNC"
> dispatch for POST "/poi/test/hello", parameters={masked}  2022-08-23
> 15:00:11.346 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=] [request_id=]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]
> DEBUG - Resume with async result ["hello"]  2022-08-23 15:00:11.346
> [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=] [request_id=]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor]
> DEBUG - Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain,
> */*, text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json, application/cbor]  2022-08-23
> 15:00:11.346 [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=] [request_id=]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor]
> DEBUG - Writing ["hello"]  2022-08-23 15:00:11.346
> [http-nio-8083-exec-5] [user=] [request_id=]
> [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] DEBUG - Exiting
> from "ASYNC" dispatch, status 200

Can someone tell me how I can fix this to get the HTTP response body from Webflux controllers?

Sample Controller:

```html
@RestController
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Mono<String> hello() {
        log.info("POI hello");
        return Mono.just("hello");//.map(ResponseEntity::ok);
    }
}
```

- **Spring boot version:** 2.2.5
- **Java version:** 8

Comment: Show us your full pom please